# Angular 8.1 project in VSCode is not showing any intellisense nor hints

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, angular8

I've updated my Angular CLI so that I'll have the latest Angular (8.1).
I've generated a new project, using `ng new`.

But it seems like no identifying of angular whatsoever:
No intellisense, no hints when I hover over variables, nothing.
Moreover - not showing errors when I'm using non-existing variables.

I have the angular service extension, but it doesn't help.

Note that my previous projects still behaves correctly:
[image: previously]

But the current doesn't

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31417

Comment: Please follow https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/pull/344

Comment: @yurzui if you can please make one of these comments - an answer, I'll be able to mark it as the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known issue in Angular and Angular language service plugin repositories.

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31417
- https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/343

The main reason of this issue is that language service plugin hasn't been updated after breaking change in Angular core project.